# Is just "Thank you, looking forward" without "to it" correct to use?

Tags: grammar, phrases, american-english, sentence

Is just "Thank you, looking forward" correct to use?

Meaning the same as "Thank you, looking forward to it".

Comment: I'd always write "Thank you" as two words.

Comment: It would sound a bit odd to say _(I'm) looking forward_ without adding _to it, to seeing you_ or whatever.

Comment: *Is just "Thank you, looking forward" without "to it" correct way?* No. It is wrong. On its own "looking forward" would, colloquially, mean "in the future" or "with reference to the future", e.g. "Looking forward, the economy will fall before it rises."